# django - 'module' object has no attribute 'serialize'

Tags: python, django

edit - this is using Python 3.3 and Django 1.6

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

views.py

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from itertools import chain

def test_queryjoin(request):
    jobmstquery = Jobmst.objects.using('database1').filter(jobmst_id=3296)
    jobdtlquery = Jobdtl.objects.using('database1').filter(jobdtl_id=3296)
    queryset = list(chain(jobmstquery, jobdtlquery))
    queryresults = serializers.serialize('python', queryset)
    return HttpResponse(queryset)
```

But when I run it I get the following error -

'module' object has no attribute 'serialize'

on this specific line -

```
queryresults = serializers.serialize('python', queryset)
```

edit - doing the following still generates the same error -

```
queryresults = serializers.serialize('json', jobmstquery)
```

same with this -

```
queryresults = serializers.serialize('json', Jobmst.objects.using('database1').filter(jobmst_id = 3296))
```

edit - This is getting weirder... it works from shell...

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from TidalDEV.models import Jobmst
jobmstquery = Jobmst.objects.using('database1').filter(jobmst_id=3296)
queryresults = serializers.serialize('json', jobmstquery)
print (queryresults)
```

Comment: Why version of Python and Django are you on? (it works like a charm here, using Python 2.7 and Django 1.6)

Comment: aha!  This explains something!  I was wondering why it worked on my lab at home and not at work.  yes, works with Python 2.6/2.7 and Django 1.6.  Doesn't work with Python 3.3 and Django 1.6.

Comment: What format are you trying to serialize to? Should it really be 'python' as your first argument to the serialize function?

Comment: Doesn't matter if I do 'json', 'xml', etc.  Always fails with the same error.  Seems to be something changed with v3.3 compared to v2.6/2.7?

Comment: Could be a number of things I guess. I had this exact problem yesterday with Django 1.6/Python 2.7. For me, removing all filtering and sorting functions fixed it. So I just do `Model.objects.all()`. Of course, that's not a very satisfying answer if you need functions.

Comment: `queryset` passed to `serialize()` is list not queryset that might be causing the issue. Try serializing one queryset.

Comment: @Rohan - updated.  same problem with doing just 1 queryset (no chain) and also putting the actual query in the serializer.

Answer (score 4):

Change
serializers.serialize('json', jobmstquery)
to
serialize('json', jobmstquery)

You are importing 'serialize' itself, so you shouldn't call it as part of the module, just on its own.